# How to remove bottom right "label" in pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am making a graph where the x-axis values are all unix timestamps. Here's the relevant code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

chart = [
    {'ts': 1584948257284, 'val': 123},
    {'ts': 1585044828000, 'val': 123},
    {'ts': 1585044828000, 'val': 128}
    # etc.
]

plt.plot([x['ts'] for x in chart], [y['val'] for y in chart])
plt.ylabel('Points')
plt.xlabel(f"{datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(start_ts)[:10]))} to {datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(close_ts)[:10]))}")
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',
    which='both',
    bottom=False,
    top=False,
    labelbottom=False
)
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False
plt.show()
```

I wind up with the scientific notation for a unix timestamp in the bottom right of the graph:

[image: Chart that I get]

What is that, and more importantly, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: `plt.xticks([])` should work here

Comment: That did work. Thank you,